# How to get the output without parenthesis or bracket because i want to add integer in the sentence?

Tags: python

I want to print the output but without parenthesis. This my example code.

```python
asa = 13
a = "Hello, World! ", asa, "Year"
print(a)
```

This the output i get:

```output
('Hello, World! ', 13, 'Year')
```

I want to print the sentence without `''` and `()` also `,`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `+` operator to concatenate strings, and turn non-string objects (like `int`) into strings by using `str(object)`:

```
asa = 13
a = "Hello, World! "+ str(asa)+ "Year"
print(a)
```

Alternatively you could use string formatting:

```
asa = 13
a = "Hello, World! {n} Year".format(n=asa)
print(a)
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use `format`, like `a = "Hello, World! {n} Year".format(n=asa)`

Comment: I'll include it in the answer

Comment: [Here's a good article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation) outlining all current string interpolation methods in Python. In fact, in most cases I would recommend string interpolation over string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are because you've created "a" as a tuple and tuples are represented with parenthesis, the same way dicts are represented with curly brackets and lists with square brackets.

Make a into a proper string instead, using the suggestions in @ibarrond's answer, or like this:

```
asa = 13
a = "Hello, World! %dYear"
print(a % asa)  # output: "Hello, World! 13Year"
```

I suspect you want a space after %d, but that's not how you wrote your code.

Answer (score 1):

@afifizain

Your code is also correct.

Let me explain you why you are getting '' () and , in your print statement.

You have assigned values to variable a with comma separator, **so your variable 'a' is not a string, it is tuple**

you can simply pass your values to print function directly instead of storing them in variable a, it will work.  You can print it like below.

```
print("Hello, World! ", asa, "Year" )
```

But if you compulsory want to store values in variable 'a' then you need to unpack those values with using * like below.

```
print(*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way of doing this in python 3.6 is:

`print(f'Hello, World! {asa}Year')`